# matplotlib ticks thickness

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to increase the thickness and size of ticks in matplotlib without having to write a long piece of code like this:

```
for line in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines():
    line.set_markersize(25)
    line.set_markeredgewidth(3)
```

The problem with this piece of code is that it uses a loop which costs usually a lot of CPU usage.

Comment: very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711338/matplotlib-ticks-position-relative-to-axis

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A simpler way is to use the `set_tick_params` function of `axis` objects:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=5)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=5)
```

Doing it this way means you can change this on a per-axis basis with out worrying about global state and with out making any assumptions about the internal structure of mpl objects.

If you want to set this for *all* the ticks in your axes,

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(width=5,...)
```

Take a look at [`set_tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params) doc and  [tick_params valid keywords](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)

Comment: Missing 's'? For me it is ax.tick_params()

Comment: @tylerswright Thank you for fixing a very long standing (and upvoted?!) typo.

Comment: how to change the width of every nth tick_params

Answer (score 24):

You can change all `matplotlib` defaults using `rcParams` like in

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set tick width
mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 20
mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 4
mpl.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 2

x = np.linspace(0., 10.)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot.setp](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp)

```
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(), 'markersize', 25)
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(), 'markeredgewidth', 3)
```

You can also use list comprehension, although not having a return value probably does not make much sense, besides reducing the number of lines in the code [see e.g. here](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/)

```
[line.set_markersize(25) for line in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
[line.set_markeredgewidth(3) for line in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines()]
```

Comment: why should a list comprehension be more efficient, if you never use the resulting list?

Comment: You're right. If I've understood [this](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/) correctly, could be even worse (for efficiency and readability). I'll edit my answer. ps,OT: this is the demonstration that something like stackoverflow is a great tool as sometimes you learn more answering questions that asking them