# matplotlib ticks position relative to axis

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way in matplotlib to set ticks between the labels and the axis as it is by default in Origin? The examples section online does not show a single plot with this feature. I like having ticks outside the plotting area because sometimes the plot hides the ticks when inside.

Comment: closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705904/matplotlib-ticks-thickness

Answer (score 34):

To set the just the major ticks:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')
plt.draw()
```

to set all ticks (minor and major),

```
ax.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
plt.draw()
```

to set both the x and y axis at the same time:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(direction='out')
```

[axis level doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params) and [axes level doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)

To shift the tick labels relative to the ticks use `pad`.  Compare

```
ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=5)
plt.draw()
```

with

```
ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=15)
plt.draw()
```

Comment: the last one seems to work fine. Now I have to find a way to move the tick labels by the same distance. In fact I mistakenly put twice the code line 'ax.tick_params(which='both', direction='out', length=25, width=6)' and surprisingly it reduced the size of the plot by the needed amount to have a perfect plot. But I don't know why.

Comment: Did you remember to include a `plt.draw()`?  You can adjust the space between the label and the tick with the `pad` kwarg.

Comment: here http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pyplot.draw#matplotlib.pyplot.draw ; they say that plt.draw() is not needed is the sequence of modification ends with show(); though I tried it before checking the definition of plt.draw(): it didn't not change anything. what is `pad`?

Comment: @user1850133 See the documentation on `tick_param` (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) It sets the space between the tick and the label.

Comment: no option allows positioning of the tick labels with tick_params

Comment: @user1850133 If this solved your problem can you please accept it?

Comment: Oddly enough, I am having the same issue, that I cannot move the ticks to the outside. It seems like the command is simply ignored. However, this seems to be related to the axis artist I am using.

Comment: To set a specific axis; ax.tick_params(direction='out', axis='x', pad=5)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

By getting the subplot object you can play with your ticks

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
yax = ax.get_yaxis()
plt.xticks(y_pos, city)
xtickNames=ax.set_xticklabels(city)
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=10)
```

[Following is the output with 45 degrees rotated ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZlOi.png)