# matplotlib tick labels position relative to axes

Tags: matplotlib

I set matplotlib to put ticks outside the plot area but now they overlap on the corresponding labels. the tick_params method does not provide any option to set the corresponding labels position.
So I guess I will have to write my own function using text() method. In the meanwhile does any one has a better suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711338/matplotlib-ticks-position-relative-to-axis related to

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To shift the tick labels relative to the ticks use pad. Compare

```
ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=5)
plt.draw()
```

with

```
ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=15)
plt.draw()
```

Comment: @user1850133 no worries.  One could argue it should have been a separate question anyway (someone looking for how to adjust the padding would not look at how to flip the ticks).

Comment: I said sorry because I said "the tick_params method does not provide any option to set the corresponding labels position" while it's not true and I nevertheless checked the documentation but it seems carelessly.

Comment: How can we pad in the other direction? (i.e. I want to offset the ticks' label to the right, because my labels are rotated and dont appear under the right bar )

Comment: @c-a I assume negative values.  You should open a new question rather than asking in the comments of a year old question.