# Matplotlib colorbar background and label placement

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Up until recently I have been using Mathematica for my plots. Although it was a real pain and everything had to be done manually, the results where very close to what I wanted. One example is the following:

[image: Mathematica example plot]

I really like the grey rounded rectangle in the background of the colorbar. While everything had to be adjusted manually in Mathematica, matplotlib is a lot more automatic and already produced nice results.

[image: Mathematica example plot]

But there are still two problems I have:

1. I don't know how to do a rounded rectangle in the background. I looked at the fancybbox patch but didn't get it to work with the colorbar as I want it to. What is the best way to get something like the Mathematica box? For the legend in plots there seems to be a fancy bbox option... but not for colorbars
2. When I use the "lesser sign" (<) the label of colorbar moves too far to the right. How can I adjust this (maybe even "in-between" the numbers as in the Mathematica plot)?

I am looking forward to any suggestions pointing in the right direction :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882249/matplotlib-aligning-y-ticks-to-the-left/15883858#15883858 <- how to adjust the padding on the tick labels

Comment: And please show us code.

Comment: Aside: very gorgeous data.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To your second question: you can use a negative `labelpad` value to move the label back towards the ticklabels, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.linspace(0, 10, num=256).reshape(16,16) 

cf = plt.contourf(data, levels=(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10))
cb = plt.colorbar(cf)

cb.set_ticklabels([r'$<10^{0}$', 1, 2, r'$10^{14}$', r'$10^{14}+12345678$'])
cb.set_label(r'$n_e$ in $m^{-3}$', labelpad=-40, y=0.45)

plt.show()
```

Using the parameter `y`, you can additionally move the label up or down for better symmetry.

The argument of `labelpad` is given in points (1/72 inch). `y` accepts values in `[0, 1]`, `0.0` is the lower border and `1.0` the upper.

The result:

[image: Script Output]

Comment: `y` is not restricted to the interval `[0.0, 1.0]`. It can take any float/integer. If `y > 1.0` the label will be placed _above_ the top of the axis, and if `y < 0.0` it will be placed _below_ the bottom of the axis. The axis coordinates are _normalized_, meaning `0.0` is the "start" and `1.0` the "end" of the axis' extent.

Comment: Just to be clear: the `[0, 1]` is _interval notation_, not list notation. Thus this means from `0` to `1`, inclusive. This applies both to the answer and the comment above.

Comment: Could you tell me where do you find these parameters like `y` and `labelpad` because I did not find them either in [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_label) or source code?

Comment: I accidentally found that `cb.set_label` is actually a [text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) and hence `y` is text properties. Still wondering how to determine more details of `**kw` found in this [page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_label).