# How to align xlabels of plot and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a simple function to plot 2D data.  I want the colorbar label on the x-axis of the colorbar, vertically aligned with the xlabel of the plot.  Here's a MWE:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def plot2d(x, y, z, xlabel, ylabel, zlabel, ax=None, **pcm_kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
    else:
        fig = ax.get_figure()
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)

    pcm_kwargs.setdefault("shading", "auto")
    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, **pcm_kwargs)

    cb = fig.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax)
    cb.ax.set_xlabel(zlabel)

    fig.align_xlabels()
    return fig, ax


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    z = np.random.random((100, 100))
    plot2d(x, y, z, xlabel="xlabel", ylabel="ylabel", zlabel="zlabel")
    plt.show()
```

First problem is that `constrained_layout=True` causes `fig.colorbar` to create an `Axes` instead of an `AxesSubplot`, so `fig.align_xlabels()` throws an error.  But even if I remove `constrained_layout=True`, the xlabel and zlabel aren't vertically aligned:

[image].

I also tried setting the label's y position directly:

```py
fig.canvas.draw()
cb.ax.xaxis.label.set_y(ax.xaxis.label.get_position()[1])
```

but still no effect.

How can I vertically align the plot and colorbar xlabels (within a `constrained_layout` if possible)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the following settings? `cb.ax.set_xlabel(zlabel, rotation=90)`

Comment: If you want the x-axis labels to be vertical as well, try the following. `ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, rotation=90)`

Comment: I don't want the text to be sideways, I want the two labels to be aligned, i.e. at the same y position

Comment: So this is how you want to do it. `cb.set_label(zlabel, loc='center')`

Comment: No, that puts the label on the y-axis of the colorbar.

Comment: If you look at the image linked in the op, I simply want the text "zlabel" to be vertically aligned with the text "xlabel", without hardcoding a labelpadding (which will break depending on the users rcparams).

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue with tick labels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984904/matplotlib-tick-label-anchor-right-align-tick-labels-on-right-side-axis-and/69123387#69123387). I've adapted it slightly for this question and this seems to work regardless of the font sizes. I tested from 7-18 point fonts.

```
cb = fig.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax)
r = plt.gcf().canvas.get_renderer()
coord = ax.xaxis.get_tightbbox(r)

xcoord = ax.xaxis.label.get_window_extent(renderer = r)
inv = ax.transData.inverted()
xcoord = inv.transform(xcoord)
xcoorddisplay = ax.transData.transform(xcoord)

cb.ax.set_xlabel(zlabel, labelpad = (xcoorddisplay[1][1]-xcoorddisplay[0][1])+8)
```