# Left aligning long y ticklabels

Tags: matplotlib, formatting, seaborn

I have a heatmap with long y tick labels. I would like to align them all to the left.

Here is a picture of what I have:
[image]

Here is the image of how I would like it to be:
[image]

I found [this page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_ticklabel_alignment.html), which does exactly what I wanted, but that is not working for me. When I try to use `ax.axis["left"].major_ticklabels.set_ha("left")` I get an error.

I also found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882249/matplotlib-aligning-y-ticks-to-the-left), but the output is coming out like this:
[image]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15883858/7758804) works without issue and seems like the best opiton: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beLSc.png)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71815278/7758804), but has the unfortunate effect of making other axes functions not work (e.g. `ax.tick_params(tick1On=False)` does noting: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmIuR.png)