# How do I change matplotlib colorbar tick marks to facing outwards?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I've noticed on the matplotlib examples gallery that all of their plots featuring vertical colorbars have tick marks on them that face inward,

(*i.e. From the edge of the bar into the colored region of the bar*).

For the types of plots and colorscales that I am using, it would be much better to have the tick marks facing outwards.

*How would I* modify this simple example from the matplotlib gallery (*see below*) to have outward facing tick marks on its colorbar?

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from pylab import *

#normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = randn(100000)
y = randn(100000)+5

hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
colorbar()
show()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib ticks position relative to axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711338/matplotlib-ticks-position-relative-to-axis)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply set the `tick_params` for the colorbar:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from pylab import *

#normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = randn(100000)
y = randn(100000)+5

hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
colorbar().ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out')
show()
```

[image: Colorbar with ticks out]