# Matplotlib interactive navigation zoom-to-rectangle button doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this Python code to plotting a figure:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

I draw each plot running a loop along x and y like this:

```
ax.plot(x, y, dotFormat)
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=errorStd, fmt=dotFormat)
```

Finally, I set the axes and show the chart with the interactive navigation:

```
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_title(chartTitle)

fontsize=10

ax.set_ylabel(yLabel, fontsize=fontsize+2)
ax.set_xlabel(xLabel+'\n', fontsize=fontsize+2)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontsize=fontsize)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(xMinorLabels)), minor=True) 
ax.set_xticklabels(xMinorLabels, minor=True, rotation=90, fontsize=fontsize-5) 
ax.set_xticks(xMajorPosition, minor=False) 
ax.set_xticklabels(xMajorLabels, minor=False, rotation=90, fontsize=fontsize-4)

plt.show()
```

If I use the tool zoom-to-rectangle and the Y-axis doesn't work property, because the same dot before zooming in is under 5, and after zooming in it is over 5.

What is happening with the y-axis when I use the zoom tool? Is a bug in the interactive navigation of matplotlib library? Without this tool, the library is useless for huge charts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontsize=fontsize)
```

section.  `set_yticklabels` sets the value of the tick *independent of the data*.  That is the third tick will **always** be the third entry of what ever you passed in.

`set_*ticklabels` should be considered dangerous and only used in very specialized situations.

You can set the font size via `ax.tick_params(...)` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705904/matplotlib-ticks-thickness/14712756#14712756)

Comment: You are completely right. I remove this entire line and it worked perfectly. The only minor problem now is where to indicate the fontsize.

Comment: @toscanelli see edit.  If this solved you problem please accept (the big gray check box on the left) the answer.